# ASP trim string in regex

Tags: regex, asp-classic, trim

Does anyone know how to trim the `$1` value?

```vb
' URL Replacement, www.Scirra.com
Dim objRegExp : set objRegExp = new RegExp
With objRegExp
    .Pattern = "\[url\](.*)\[\/url]"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
End With
strMessage = objRegExp.replace(strMessage, "<a href=""$1"" rel=""nofollow"">$1</a>")
set objRegExp = nothing
```

Example, if I enter:

```
[url] http://www.scirra.com[/url]
```

This renders as an unclickable link because of the `%20` before it.  What I'd like to do is something like:

```
strMessage = objRegExp.replace(strMessage, "<a href=""" & trim($1) & """ rel=""nofollow"">" & trim($1) & "</a>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your capturing group with `\s*` and, while you're at it, change the pattern to avoid using `.*` (you want to capture everything but a `[` or a space -- use a complemented character class):

```
.Pattern = "\[url\]\s*([^\[\s]+)\s*\[/url\]"
```

(note: not sure the `[` needs escaping in the character class)

Answer (score 1):

Revising the pattern is a good solution such a case. 
As alternative;
The **Replace** method of **RegExp** object has a callback functionality which you can use as an alternative to pattern revisions.
Sometimes, callback functionality may be necessary to handle more complex patterns.
And additionally, I'd use a pattern like `\[url\]([^[]*)\[/url\]` instead of `\[url\](.*)\[\/url]`.
Check the matches with an expression that contains more than one bbcode, you'll see why I suggest.

```vb
' URL Replacement, www.Scirra.com

Function cb_CreateLink(sMatch, sGroup1, iMatchStartPos, sSubjectText)
    cb_CreateLink = "<a href="""& Trim(sGroup1) &""" rel=""nofollow"">"& Trim(sGroup1) &"</a>"
End Function

Dim strMessage : strMessage = "[url] http://www.scirra.com[/url]   [url] http://www.scirra.com[/url]"
Dim objRegExp : set objRegExp = new RegExp
With objRegExp
    .Pattern = "\[url\]([^[]*)\[/url\]"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
End With
strMessage = objRegExp.replace(strMessage, GetRef("cb_CreateLink"))
set objRegExp = Nothing

Response.Write strMessage
```

**Note that:** The referenced function structure is variable by depending to the number of groups in the pattern.

> **CallBackFunction** ( **Match** *string*, [,**Group1** *string*, **Group2** *string*, ...], **MatchStartPosition** *long*, **OriginalText** *string* )